# Having a variable which is same for all the clients of the site in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am creating an event in which if one user submitted the problem correctly all the users will be forwarded to the next question. For this, I have implemented by storing a variable in the database for knowing if the solution is submitted or not. Problem is that Like 100 people will be playing the same event at the same time so for all the users we have to check repeatedly in the database that is the problem submitted or not which kind of seems hectic.
Is there any better way to implement this like having a variable which is common to all the users?

Comment: Lots of options.  In-memory databases, shared memory, standard caches, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could use ajax in your client side to check for updates every 5 seconds.

When a user updates the correct answer you can store the answer in a cache like memcache / redis. The function the ajax request triggers will see if there is a answer in the cache, and it will return true. In your client side JS you can check if the returned response of the AJAX was true and then proceed to the next question.

So for example you will send a ajax request to `/getupdate` with a ID of the current session or similar, the `/getupdate` page will execute a function which will look for the ID in the caching server, if the ID exists it means the question is answered so it will either return `TRUE` or the value of the answer. In the client side, you can check if the value is `FALSE` and if it is, don't do anything, if they value is not FALSE, you can have the next question updated, or show the answer to the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Web Sockets(like Ratchet) and broadcast to the whole server. Each client connected will listen the message and you will have to define a state storing current question, meanwhile you can update the database storing the current order of question in case if anyone disconnects you can assure everyone gets the same order upon reconnecting.

Making AJAX calls will also do if you don't mind the delay between timeouts, which in your case does matter.